# React Native scene doesn't update from Parse promise

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, react-native

I'm currently playing around with React Native and have decided to set my app up with Parse (parse.com).

I've come upon a strange bug with React Native and Parse promises - when I pass a Parse Promise a callback it runs everything in the callback but nothing changes in my scene. Essentially when the Parse promise resolves the UI doesn't update - but after I tap the screen all the updates happen as expected.

Here's a code snippet, I'm trying to navigate to a new scene after a successful log in through Parse. All I'm doing is passing a navigator object a new route. "Login successful" and "Navigate function called" are both outputted to the console, but the scene does not transition at first. But after I tap the screen anywhere, the scene transitions as expected to before.

```
var navigate = function(object) {
  console.log("Navigate function called!");
  this.props.navigator.push(/* route object */);
}.bind(this);

Parse.User.logIn("email", "password").then(
  function(object) {
    console.log("Login successful!");
    navigate(object);
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  },
);
```

Any thoughts/insights on what might be happening?

Note: I tried the same bit of code with regular Javascript Promises, for example:

```
new Promise(resolve, reject)) ...)
```

and everything worked as expected. A different version with a setTimeout worked as well. So my conclusion from that is that React Native does handle promise callbacks and asynchronous calls (the problem isn't from that).

To make sure that it's not a bug in React Native's `navigator`, I also tried updating my views with a `setState` call and the exact same problem occurred. Maybe the Parse promise is not updating the main thread somehow? Or maybe the way Parse promises are implemented is causing the React Native view to freeze up?

Comment: That rather sounds as if parse promise asynchrony makes react miss the update to `this.props.navigator`, than that the promise blocks the thread.

Comment: @Bergi Could you suggest how I should rephrase the question then? I don't have much experience with iOS so I may have made an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Just use "React (Native) page doesn't update from Parse promise" or so for the title. The rest of your question seems fine, I guess only the phrase "blocks the thread" threw me off.

Comment: `Promise.resolve(Parse.User.logIng(…)).then(…)` might work. If yes, than that's probably the solution, although I'm not skilled enough in react to know the exact reason.

Comment: Changed the title, thanks for the suggestion. `Promise.resolve` unfortunately does not work. I think you might be right in that the problem is more on the React side not recognizing the update than on the Parse promise side.

Comment: Could it be that you have to write `navigate(object).bind(this);` as your call instead of the `.bind(this)` at the end of the function defintion? could be that `this`is not what you want it to be ...

Comment: That's not it @MrMuetze because the navigator transition eventually does happen, but just not when expected to.

Comment: @Warren, Parse promises are based on the jQuery ones (https://api.jquery.com/promise/) so can you try to reproduce this without Parse? Just implement a jQuery Promise that execute any HTTP request (to mimic the Parse behavior) and see what happens.

Comment: @RafaelMunoz thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the npm jQuery package requires modules to have access to the browser `document`, but React Native is not in the browser. Is there a different way to test what you're getting at?

Comment: Since I hadn't tried a real HTTP request, I just tried a "GET" with the default Javascript Promise and XMLHTTPRequest. It worked as expected, updating the UI correctly after receiving the response. Maybe it's just that the jQuery promise implementation creates a thread bug? I could be totally wrong. Thoughts @RafaelMunoz?

Comment: Sounds like the JS event loop isn't being spun along. In addition to calling `navigate(object)`, can you also mutate some local state on the React component that this code lives on? E.g. `this.setState({loggedIn: true});`

Comment: @PhilippvonWeitershausen I tried this and those changes don't show up until tapping the screen as well... any idea on how to get the JS event loop going again?

Comment: I can't think of an obvious solution, or reason for the bug. If you can put together a minimal example that reproduces the problem, we can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when trying to use ES6 Promises (or any other third party promise library).  I was able to resolve it by using react-native's local promise implementation.

```
Promise = require('react-native/Libraries/Promise');
```

I know you are using parse, so a pull request may be required to get parse promises to return react-native promises. Hope this help someone as I spent a few days dumbfounded on it.